# ! Package tikz Error: missing semicolon

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, arrows, shapes

I have found this sample of code from here: [Block diagram generation in LaTeX](http://me.berkeley.edu/~maxchen/_static/block_diagram_in_latex.pdf). Initially I had some problems while I was compiling the code and I solved them due to copy paste features some of the characters where altered. Although that the code seems correct to me, I keep getting this error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?.

 See the tikz package documentation for explanation.
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

 l.20 \draw [->] (controller)
                                �� node[name=u] {$u(k)$} (system);
 ?
```

Since I am new to tikz package I can not see the error, all parts of the node seems to have the semi-column. What am I missing here?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=4em]
%fill=blue!20
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate] \tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
\node [block, right of=sum, node distance=3.5cm] (controller) {$C(z^{-1})$};
\node [block, right of=controller, pin={[pinstyle]above:$d(k)$}, node distance=4cm] (system) {$P(z^{-1})$};
\draw [->] (controller) – node [name=u] {$u(k)$} (system);
\node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
\node [block, below of=u] (measurements) {$F(z^{-1})$};
\draw [draw,->] (input) – node {$r(k)$} (sum);
\draw [->] (sum) – node {$e(k)$} (controller);
\draw [->] (system) – node [name=y] {$y(k)$}(output);
\draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
\draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} node [near end] {$y_m(k)$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `--` have been converted to an en-dash from your editor. you need to replace them.

Comment: Your posted code contains strange characters/control characters, e.g. at `(controller) - node` and similar lines. Remove those and it should work.

Comment: I think you have an en-dash (–) instead of a hyphen (-).  Hard to spot in most fonts, but the black ? marks in the error are a bit of a give away.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem due to invisible characters in the input

Comment: @egreg you mean I should change the title of the question? Because the code and errors are reproducible? Thanks for the advices.

Comment: @Thanos You have the wrong character; the documentation says you must have `--` which is not an en-dash (although in normal text `--` results in an en-dash). Wrong syntax: off topic. This doesn't mean your question was bad, but that it's unlikely it can help other readers.

Comment: @egreg I understand what you mean, well I did not find the point that mentions about the `--` but I noticed that the example was modified based on [link](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/control-system-principles/) where the code is compiling properly. Thank you for your time and guidance to learn more.

Comment: @egreg It actually helped me :) I was working on the manual and copied/pasted code and got the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely right @Johannes_B, something so small can produce so many problems when someone has never used tikz. Thank you all for your time and effort. I will also post the updated version just in case that someone might occur the same error as me.

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,automata}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=4em] %fill=blue!20
\tikzstyle{sum} = [draw, fill=blue!20, circle, node distance=1cm]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate] \tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,thin,black}]

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
\node [input, name=input] {};
\node [sum, right of=input] (sum) {};
\node [block, right of=sum, node distance=3.5cm] (controller) {$C(z^{-1})$};
\node [block, right of=controller, pin={[pinstyle]above:$d(k)$}, node distance=4cm] (system) {$P(z^{-1})$};
\draw [->] (controller) -- node [name=u] {$u(k)$} (system);
\node [output, right of=system] (output) {};
\node [block, below of=u] (measurements) {$F(z^{-1})$};
\draw [draw,->] (input) -- node {$r(k)$} (sum);
\draw [->] (sum) -- node {$e(k)$} (controller);
\draw [->] (system) -- node [name=y] {$y(k)$}(output);
\draw [->] (y) |- (measurements);
\draw [->] (measurements) -| node[pos=0.99] {$-$} node [near end] {$y_m(k)$} (sum);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```