# Strange circuitikz error

Tags: circuitikz

I'm getting a strange error when using circuitikz.  I compiled the following code successfully

```
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (1,2) node[and port] (and1) {}
          (1,4) node[and port] (and2) {}
          (-2,1) node (Z) {Z}
          (-2,2) node (JAMN) {JAMN}
          (-2,3) node (N) {N}
          (-2,4) node (JAMZ) {JAMZ}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

However, I changed up the coords of Z, JAMN, N, and JAMZ to make the diagram prettier.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (1,2) node[and port] (and1) {}
          (1,4) node[and port] (and2) {}
          (-2,1.5) node (Z) {Z}
          (-2,2.5) node (JAMN) {JAMN}
          (-2,3.5) node (N) {N}
          (-2,4.5) node (JAMZ) {JAMZ}
\end{circuitikz}
\end{center}
```

When I changed the code, I got the following error:

```
! Package tikz Error: Giving up on this path. Did you forget a semicolon?
```

I checked out [! Package tikz Error: missing semicolon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165306/package-tikz-error-missing-semicolon), and I may have the same problem, but I can't find where the error is occurring.  Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: The commands in TikZ and other related packages need to be finalized with a semicolon. You are missing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\draw (1,2) node[and port] (and1) {}
      (1,4) node[and port] (and2) {}
      (-2,1) node (Z) {Z}
      (-2,2) node (JAMN) {JAMN}
      (-2,3) node (N) {N}
      (-2,4) node (JAMZ) {JAMZ};
                             ^^^^
```

as the error message already said.

Comment: Thank you.  Now everything works.  The confusing part was that the tex file initially compiled WITHOUT the semi-colon, but then failed to compile after that initial compilation.